# Scalar Function vs Stored Proc vs INSERT INTO new Table

Tags: sql-server, function

A) After creating the function and calling it in my query, I noticed that it returns both ‘Qualified’ and ‘NULL’ results in the ‘Reports’ column. And this is not good for obvious reasons. Simplifying the logic behind it is what’s driving me nuts. How do I add a clause - where a clause cannot be added? Do I have to alter the function with some conversion, insert the results into a table and then do a function, maybe another variable? What am I missing?

B) My whole argument is, why can I not add a WHERE clause when querying the [dbo].[FactInternetSales] table with the function in the SELECT statement? Should this alteration be made in the function itself to be able to return a result with a WHERE clause? and if so, how do I go about doing just that?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ExTaxQual]
                    (@Val1 money 
                    ,@Val2 money) 
                    RETURNS char(4) AS
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @result char(4) 

            IF (@Val1 + @Val2) > 1000
                SET @result = 'Qualified'
                ELSE
                SET @result = NULL
            RETURN
                    @result
    END
```

And my query:

```
SELECT 
        [ExtendedAmount]
       ,[TaxAmt]
       ,[dbo].[ExTaxQual]([ExtendedAmount]
                ,[TaxAmt]) AS 'Reports'
FROM
        [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
```

Result..

> SELECT 
>         [ExtendedAmount]
>        ,[TaxAmt]
>        ,[dbo].[ExTaxQual]([ExtendedAmount]
>                  ,[TaxAmt]) AS 'Reports' FROM       [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
>   ------------------------*/
>
> (60398 row(s) affected)

Which is not nearly consistent enough.

B) Maybe the example below is a bit clearer

```
SELECT [ExtendedAmount]
      ,[TaxAmt]
      ,[dbo].[ExTaxQual](
                         [ExtendedAmount]
                        ,[TaxAmt]) 
AS Report

FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales]

WHERE [ExtendedAmount] + [TaxAmt] = 'Qualified'
------------------------------VS
SELECT [ExtendedAmount],
       [TaxAmt],
       'Qualified' AS Reports
FROM   [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
WHERE  [ExtendedAmount] + [TaxAmt] > 1000
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And while you're at it: What is your input? Which parameter values result in a `NULL` value?

Comment: @papatoob the params are the two amounts added to be equated to the 'result'>1000. I do not want the function to show where the param is NULL

Comment: I didn't get that at all from the question. See NewUser's answer then...

Comment: I've edited my question as best I can. @papatoob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take report only for qualified records then use this.

```
SELECT [ExtendedAmount],
       [TaxAmt],
       'Qualified' AS Reports
FROM   [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
WHERE  [ExtendedAmount] + [TaxAmt] > 1000
```

This query gives report of qualified and not qualified records. Here you wont require function at all.

```
SELECT [ExtendedAmount],
       [TaxAmt],
       CASE
         WHEN [ExtendedAmount] + [TaxAmt] > 1000 THEN 'Qualified'
         ELSE 'Not Qualified'
       END AS Reports
FROM   [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
```

Comment: This helped. its funny because I did run it a few times before I asked the question and it kept returning the column names without data. it was probably a bad query. ThanQ man :)

Comment: The first one is what I needed to query against the function. Works perfect. unfortunately I cannot vote your answer as I am still new.